# Images uploaded with Node server cannot be found by Angular 2

Tags: node.js, angular

I have an app in Angular 2, decided to add real server, Node JS, to upload documents and do other things.

```
Browser => Angular [localhost:4200/api/documents] => Node [localhost:3000/documents]
```

This is how I start them together using **scripts** in **package.json**

```
"scripts": {
    "server-start": "gulp",
    "client-start": "ng serve --verbose --proxy-config server.conf.json",
    "start": "npm-run-all -p client-start server-start"
}
```

So, when I run npm start it starts 2 parallel processes - Node JS using Gulp and Angular using ng serve. Angular is a front end, but all URLs that start with **/api** get redirected to Node. Here is how it's done with **server.config.js**

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://localhost:3000",
    "secure": false
  }
}
```

Node JS receives stream from Angular with image and saves it in Angular assets folder, so uploaded image should be available in Angular, but when I try to open uploaded image in browser it returns me 404, not found. Just in case, this is part of my **.angular-cli.json**

```
"root": "src",
"outDir": "dist",
"assets": [
  "assets",
  "favicon.ico",
  "service-worker.js"
],
"index": "index.html",
"main": "main.ts"
```

Example, I have existing image that was there before **ng serve**

```
F:\Node\cms\src\assets\uploads\1.jpg
```

available at, it works

```
http://localhost:4200/assets/uploads/1.jpg
```

I upload new one to the same location

```
F:\Node\cms\src\assets\uploads\5.jpg
```

but it's NOT available at

```
http://localhost:4200/assets/uploads/5.jpg
```

When I restart my servers image becomes available. According to [this discussion](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5268) **ng serve** performs deployment of Angular app in the background, and folder dist is empty, all images are taken from memory, and any new images dropped into assets won't be available, correct me if I am wronng.

**Question #1:** is built-in Angular server able to handle dynamic images if they were added when application is already running in memory?

**Question #2:** looks like in complex apps **ng serve** brings more troubles than benefits, is it worth to try to make it working or you'd recommend to start using **ng build** instead?

Comment: You need to set up a static route in node for that folder because node does not have access to that location

Comment: @Judson Terrell : the thing is the upload in Node works fine, so problem is for sure in Angular. To prove this I tried to start Angular with ng serve and then added image manually to Angular's assets folder - still doesn't work. Upload in Node is just an example of what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: That's very strange. You need to probable let node handle all of your file paths and return them all on port 3000. I use a configuration file in my angular app to append the URL:PORT of the node instance dynamically on the image paths. For static images I just point to the angular assets folder.

Comment: Anything you out in source assets should be in your build folder

Comment: I think, idea with a separate URL for images may work within Node, need to try this

Comment: I actually love doing it this way. If you need code example let me know. You need to do app.get('/someFolder,function (){ return the modern server path and image to the uploads folder using writeFile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when running your application, everything points to build folder. Not "src"

You probably are wiping out the images each time you run my serve or need to store them in a different location.

You are technically storing images on a "server" so I recommend using node to retrieve the paths to these files.

Answer (score 1):

You should use ng build instead of ng serve. ng serve is meant for dev purposes. See https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/serve

Additionally after running ng build you will need to have the dist folder on an actual server. Here's an example from the Angular wiki
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-disk-serve

`ng build --watch`

`lite-server --baseDir="dist"`

You could also have node serving the dist folder using the static method that is built into node. 
The line to add would be either

`app.use(express.static('dist'))`

or

`app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')))`

See https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

I prefer to do ng build -aot to get the bundle size as small as possible and then serve the dist folder with nginx.